# Burn to mint solidity

Tags: solidity, linux-mint, cryptocurrency, erc20

Ok so I have an issue and I'm not even sure where to begin. I NEED a burn to mint function within a smart contract for an erc20 token. It's on a 1:1 ratio version 1 for version 2. All that I've seen in my 4 hours of searching is more or less websites or dapps that do the transfer when a wallet is attached. Thank you for your time .

Answer (score 0):

Not possible unless the version 1 already implements its part.

In the example below:

1. Deploy `Version1`
2. Deploy `Version2`, passing it the `Version1` address
3. Pass the `Version2` address to `Version1` function `setVersion2Address()`
4. Verify the deployer token balances using the `balanceOf()` function on both contracts - the deployer now has 1000 tokens of `Version1` and 0 tokens of `Version2`
5. Invoke `burnToMint()` on `Version2`, passing it the `1000` tokens as arguments
6. Verify the deployer token balances using the `balanceOf()` function on both contracts - the deployer now has 0 tokens of `Version1` and 1000 tokens of `Version2`

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Version1 is ERC20, Ownable {
    address version2;

    modifier onlyVersion2 {
        require(msg.sender == version2);
        _;
    }

    constructor() ERC20("Version 1", "v1") {
        _mint(msg.sender, 1000);
    }

    function setVersion2Address(address _version2) external onlyOwner {
        version2 = _version2;
    }

    function version2Burn(address from, uint256 amount) external onlyVersion2 {
        _burn(from, amount);
    }
}

contract Version2 is ERC20 {
    Version1 version1;

    constructor(Version1 _version1) ERC20("Version 2", "v2") {
        version1 = _version1;
    }

    function burnToMint(uint256 amount) external {
        version1.version2Burn(msg.sender, amount);
        _mint(msg.sender, amount);
    }
}
```